# Copy Video from Mac to iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, video, file-transfer

How can I copy my video from my Mac and send it to my iPhone via a cable or wireless?

Comment: Is the iPhone set up to sync with iTunes on your Mac?

Comment: @SynestheticSymphony yes it is sync

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends on how you plan to play it on the iPhone. Both following ways require iTunes and an iPhone connected to it by cable or wireless.

1. If you want to copy it to your Media library and play it natively you will need to:

   - Select your device
   - Click on **Movies** tab
   - Check **Sync Movies** and check the desired movie from your iTunes library
2. If you use an app (such as VLC) to play it you will need to:

   - Select your device
   - Click on **Apps** tab
   - Scroll to **File Sharing** and select desired app from list
   - Press on **Add..** button and select desire movie from file chooser dialog

Alternately, you can share/stream your movie to your iPhone over wireless connection if you don't want to take it with you.

Answer (score 2):

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) is always an answer when transferring/syncing files to your iPhone.  It's easy; just drop a file in your Dropbox folder and it will show up on your iPhone after a bit.  No plugging or syncing required.

Comment: I avoiding use software that sent my file to their server. There is some file which it is confidential.

Comment: If your movies are confidential, might be good to keep them off your iPhone altogether.

Comment: yes might be, but i need to deliver the video to client. Which it is will be easier carry with iPhone. My Video is on MAC.

Comment: Good point.  You might consider an encrypted USB key as another, perhaps even safer, option.

Answer (score 0):

TransPhone is always an answer when transferring/syncing files from computer to your iPhone. It's easy and compatible with Mac system; just add a video file in your finder folder and it will show up on your iPhone after a few steps.
If your movies are less than 50 files, the free demo might be good to copy them onto your iPhone altogether.

Comment: URL: http://www.transphone.net/

Comment: Holy Cow!!! This software is $40!!!  No way it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command line as well. Install homebrew from https://brew.sh and then simply:

```
brew install libimobiledevice
```

The documentation for the project is quite good - on par or better than Apple's manual pages and the community is quite active on fixes and updates.